# Move a skspritenode while changing its texture

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

So. A (hopefully) simple question. I have a spritenode in a game I am making. I want the character to animate its legs while it is moving. I can get it to animate its legs then move, on key press. But I cant get it to do both at the same time.

Here is my code (naturally I also have the other 3 directions laid out prior.):

‘’’

```
 case 0x7C /* LEFT */:
        TextureChangeIceMan1 = [SKAction animateWithTextures:[IcedMan returnMovementArrayWithKey: @"0x7C"] timePerFrame:0.1];

        MoveIceMan1 = [SKAction moveByX:[IcedMan returnCharacterSpeed] y:0.0 duration:0.4];
    break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"keyDown:'%@' keyCode: 0x%02X", theEvent.characters, theEvent.keyCode);
        break;
}
TextureChangeIceMan1 = [SKAction repeatActionForever: TextureChangeIceMan1]; //make it unending
[IceMan1 runAction: MoveIceMan1];
[IceMan1 runAction: TextureChangeIceMan1];
```

‘’’

Comment: Maybe the method what are you showing are executes every time, you need only run TextureChangeIceMan1 one time and MoveIceMan1 every time. I really recommend you use a GKStateMachine to change IceMan1 from one state like "idle" to another like "running", there you can have more control.

Comment: there has to be other factors at play here. there is no issue assigning two actions to an object. they do not override each other or run in succession. so something else in your code must be causing an issue

Comment: Your right, this action does execute every time. I’ll give it a shot

Comment: Maetschl, your idea worked. If you want to set it as the answer to this question I can mark it as correct.